access-control-allow-origin: undefined not blocking the GET response
My browser which has loaded https://www.cashrewards.com.au/shop, is making a request to the following domain, as you can see in the screenshot:
https://e-11283.adzerk.net


Why is this response not blocked by the same origin policy?
If the .gif being downloaded behind the scenes is on another domain, then shouldn't the response be blocked by the Same Origin Policy since it has access-control-allow-origin: undefined?
I don't understand why undefined is used, but since it's not * or cashrewards.com.au, I would have thought the response would be blocked?

It looks a bit odd to me as well. However I would like to point out that the status code is not affected by the same origin policy, so it's likely to be 200 even if the request is blocked by the browser.

What is triggering that request? Most likely, it's an img element in the document; the Same-Origin Policy allows that by default, without involving the CORS protocol at all. There may be CORS headers in the response, but they're immaterial, in that case.

@jub0bs yeah it's an img tag. That explains it then! Thankyou.
